# testing error with rspec and factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to use the user generated by factory girl in my rails app .The goal is to log him in and check his  edit page but it ain't working. 
What i'm getting is

```
<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `user' for #<Class:0x000001034caaa0> (NameError)
```

Here is the code that' get executed

```
describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    describe "page" do
    # signin method in utilities
    before { visit signin_path }
    fill_in "Email",       with: user.email
    fill_in "Password",    with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"           
    # end signin method in utilities
    before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: "Update your profile") }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") } 
    it { should have_link('change', href: 'htttp://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do 
      before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
      before { click_button "Save changes"}

      it { should have_content('error') }

    end



      describe "with valid information" do 
        before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
        let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
        let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
        before do
          fill_in "Name",                     with: new_name
          fill_in "Email",                    with: new_email
          fill_in "Password",                 with: user.password
          fill_in "Confirm Password",         with: user.password

          click_button "Save changes"
        end

        it { should have_selector('title',  text: new_name) }
        it { should have_link('Sign out',   href: signout_path) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
        specify { user.reload.name.should == new_name }
        specify { user.reload.email.should == new_email }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `user` variable can't be used directly within the `describe` block. Use it inside `it`, `let`, `before` or `subject` blocks (or a few others). In this case I think you meant for it to be inside of a `before` block.

Turn this:

```
describe "page" do
# signin method in utilities
before { visit signin_path }
fill_in "Email",       with: user.email
fill_in "Password",    with: user.password
click_button "Sign in"           
# end signin method in utilities
before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

it { should have_selector('h1', text: "Update your profile") }
it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") } 
it { should have_link('change', href: 'htttp://gravatar.com/emails') }
end
```

Into this:

```
describe "page" do
  before do
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"           
    visit edit_user_path(user)
  end

  it { should have_selector('h1', text: "Update your profile") }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") } 
  it { should have_link('change', href: 'htttp://gravatar.com/emails') }
end
```

Comment: @skip87 You're very welcome. I do this same thing by accident every once in a while, too.